# ssh tunnel limitations are failed on android/ios clients

Tags: linux, ssh, limit

I'm using a couple of vm's as an ssh tunnel-vpn for both android and iOS, using ssh clients on both OS's. so now i want to limit the number of sessions per each user in order for each user is limited to 1 session at a time. for example: let's say i created 20 users and enabled password authentication for these users ( user1 ,...user20 ).

I have already tried setting these limits to 1 in

```
sshd_config: maxsessions=1, maxstartups =1
```

and "`* hard maxlogins 1`" & "`* soft maxlogins 1`" in limits.conf my PAM settings are pretty straight forward too.

now the interesting part is that when I try to ssh into the vm with a user,let's say user10(ssh user10@server ), the limit works and I can not ssh to it on any other devices, but for ssh clients on the phone (that is used for only tunneling the phone and using the ssh ass a vpn) it doesn't . I can tunnel more than 100 phones when using this vm.

basically I want each user to be able to tunnel only one device at a time and not any more than that, sort of a device limit for the connection

I reckoned the problem is that maybe the issue stems from something I don't know or am not considering.

I wondered maybe the process for tunneling a phone using ssh clients is far different from ssh-ing to a VM

apps I've used on phone: napsternet for iOS and matsuri for Android

any help is appreciated

Comment: I think `ssh -N` is the edge case. See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1784450/432690). There `ssh -N` was also a problem; not the main problem though, still I believe I solved it too in my answer. I'm not sure if and how you can fix your current solution, but maybe you can implement the other asker's solution.